# Не добавляется динамически кнопка в stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, button, stackpanel

Хочу сделать так, чтобы в `stackpanel` было столько кнопок, сколько файлов есть в определенной папке. Считаю эти файлы с помощью отдельного файла, где и их число и записывается( я понимаю, что это кривая фигня). Считает количество файлов оно исправно, но по какой то причине кнопки не добавляются совсем.

```
public StackPanel stackPanel = new();
public Open_KillTeam_List op_KT_list;

public Open_KillTeam_List()
{
    Border border = new Border() { };
    InitializeComponent();
    for (int i = 0; i <= File.ReadLines("D:\\Visual studio\\C#\\Kill Team\\Kill Team\\KT_Lists\\Paths (Dont Touch).txt").Count(); i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Name = "File";
        button.Height = 50;
        button.Width = 658;
        button.FontSize = 30;
        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.OrangeRed);
        button.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        button.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;

        // stackPanel.Children.Add(button);
        // stackPanel.Children.Add(border);
        button.Content = stackPanel;
        // op_KT_list.UpdateLayout();
    }
}
```

Код XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Kill_Team.Open_KillTeam_List"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kill_Team"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Closing="Window_Closing"
        Title="Open" Height="450" Width="800" MaxHeight="450" MaxWidth="800" MinHeight="450" MinWidth="800" Background="DarkSlateGray">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        
        <Button
            Name="Open_Explorer" 
            Content="Open Explorer"
            FontSize="30"
            Width="280"
            Height="80"
            Background="OrangeRed"
            Foreground="White"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="1"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Panel.ZIndex="1"
            Click="Open_Explorer_Click"/>
        <Button
            Name="Cancel" 
            Content="Cancel"
            FontSize="30"
            Width="280"
            Height="80"
            Background="OrangeRed"
            Foreground="White"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="1"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Panel.ZIndex="1"
            Click="Cancel_Click"/>
        
        <ScrollViewer
            Name="KT_Lists" 
            FontSize="30"
            Width="700"
            Height="250"
            Background="DarkGray"
            Foreground="Black"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Panel.ZIndex="1">

            
            <StackPanel>

              
            </StackPanel>

        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Я и с `Children.Add` пытался, и с `button.Content`, но по какой то причине ничего из этого не работает. Вот как выглядит эта `stackpanel` в окне:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот эта серая зона должна быть заполнена кнопками в соответствие с числом файлов.

Мой вопрос: Почему кнопки не создаются в окне?

Comment: Потому что `.Count()` возвращает 0? Ну либо проблема за пределами показанного кода. А стекпанель вы где в окно добавляете? А в XAML разметке что?.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. .Count() возвращает 0?  Я дебагом проверял, оно исправно считает файлы

Comment: Ваш `Count()` не считает файлы, он считает строки в текстовом файле.

Comment: Это я и имел в виду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не пишите никогда свой код в конструкторе. Писать разметку окна в C# - это тоже неудобно и чревато сюрпризами, научитесь использовать привязки данных.

Создать коллекцию и назначить `DataContext`

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new();

public Open_KillTeam_List()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    Loaded += Open_KillTeam_List_Loaded;
}
```

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}"
                    Margin="3"
                    Height="50" Width="658"
                    FontSize="30"
                    Background="OrangeRed"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Click="ItemsButton_Click"/>
        </Datatemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Положите это в свой `<ScrollViewer>` и готово.

Теперь в обработчики

```
private void Open_KillTeam_List_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Items.Add("Привет");
    Items.Add("Мир");
}

private void ItemsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    MessageBox.Show((string)btn.DataContext);
}
```

---

По умолчанию `ItemsControl` использует `StackPanel`. Но если надо поменять на другую панель или настройки `StackPanel`, то это сделать легко

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: А Loaded здесь это что?

Comment: @mendzek Событие возникающее при загрузке окна. Вы можете вместо строчки в конструкторе, прописать это в XAML вверху, где размеры окна задаются `Loaded="Open_KillTeam_List_Loaded"`, а из C# убрать.

Comment: @mendzek в конструкторе вы работаете с неинициализированным окном, не надо этого делать. Вместо этого я и предложил использовать `Loaded`.

Comment: Я понимаю, я просто хочу проверить работает ли

Comment: Благодарю, в ожесточенной битве с кодом я вроде как победил с вашей помощью, и оно работает, но непонятно, почему у ObservableCollection обязательно должна быть get

Comment: @mendzek потому что привязки можно делать только к свойствам, а к полям нельзя. Изучите разницу между полями и свойствами.